# Generating and customizing equals/hashcode methods with CXF/JAXB2

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have two classes `A` and `B` generated by `cxf-codegen-plugin` from my WSDL. `A` inherits from `B`.

I would like to add common methods like `hashCode()`, `equals()`... So, I have the following configuration in my POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/wsdl/PeeringApi.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-xjc-XhashCode</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-xjc-Xequals</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-xjc-Xsetters</extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> </plugin>
```

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to generate an `equals()` method that doesn't compare properties of `B` (i.e. not calling `super.equals()`)?
2. How to indicate to the plugin to generate an `equals()` method that compare only certain properties of `A` (by default, it seems that all the properties are compared) that I specify?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution as it is explained here: http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/JAXB2+Basics+Plugins.

You can add custom bindings to indicate to JAXB2 plugins to ignore a certain property.

Comment: Wrong plugin, not cxf-*-plugin.

Comment: The `cxf-codegen-plugin` is being used to generate the source code from .wsdl and .xsd files during the maven build process. In the background it also uses the `jaxb2-basics` library to generate `equals` and `hashCode` methods as specified with the xjc args and in the bindings file.